# Getting user's IP through Load Balancer and HTTPS

Tags: https, load-balancing

My app is hosted on multiple servers through a Load Balancer and requires HTTPS at all times.

So, now I have a real challenge grabbing the client's IP. I've setup a server to do this where I run an AJAX call to another non-balanced server that returns their IP as a JSONP string. Unfortunately that server gets bombarded and slows down web sites.

Can anyone recommend a better way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to configure your load balancer so that the end points can still access the source ip.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I was told that since it is accessing through 443 (HTTPS) the x-forwarded-for header isn't passed.

Comment: It depends on your load balancer and potentially your environment. SSL terminates at our load balancer so maybe that is the difference (not SSL from the load balancer to end points).